# How to determine adminP is running properly?

Tags: ibm-domino

Currently, based on admin4.nsf or Administration Requests.
I have seen multiple request like on the following:

1. Add Server To Cluster
2. Approve Mail File Deletion
3. Approve Replica Deletion
4. Change HTTP Password in Domino Directory
5. Delete Person in Domino Directory
6. Put Server Notes BUild Number into Server Record
7. Recertify Person in Domino Directory
8. Set Directory Filename
9. Store Server's CPU count
10. Store Servers Platform in Server Record
11. Update Client Information in Person Record
12. Update Servers Protocol Information.

I was not sure if these are really pendings. I have seen documents have already processed but mostly of them have no status. I've also tried to push the requests using 'tell adminp p all'. Still the pile of list still the same. Hoping for your answer or idea. Thanks

Comment: It would be usefull to get some additional information according to your environment. How many domino server, are there cluster, do they replicate. Another good information would be the date from the "store server´s CPU count" and the information if the server was changed or is an older one.

Comment: There are two domino server, and it setup as replicate and cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests have been processed, if they have at least one response document (little twistie next to their name). The response tells you, if processing was successfull or not. 
But some of your processes still wait for approval and will not be processed until an admin approves by opening them and clicking the right action. (E.g., "Approve Mail file deletion" and "Approve replica deletion").

So: without knowing, if there are responses, we do not know, if your admin4 runs correctly.

But: most of the requests you list have to be done by the administration server of the domain. If the documents are not replicated to that server or the server is not running / invalid, then they will never be processed.